# Sending Message to user using Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to send message to fb user using facbook graph API or any other way.
I want to send message and link to facebook user via my web app.

Many Thanks,

M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible with the Send Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

There is a Send Button too, and of course the user has to enter the message - you would not be allowed to prefill it anyway. It is not possible to send messages to other users with PHP. The Chat API is deprecated: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/.